# Get access to the "header" in Angular's $htttpBackend when using the "whenPost - respond" method

Tags: angularjs

I am using the $httpBackend to mock a backend and I want to get access to the headers when I have a request:

```
$httpBackend.whenPOST('/movies').respond(function(method, url, data) {

    // How do I get access to the headers.

    // I want to check the headers and retrieve a token.

    var params = angular.fromJson(data),
        movie = MoviesDataModel.addOne(params),
        movieId = movie.id; // get the id of the new resource to populate the Location field

    return [201, movie, { Location: '/movies/' + movieId }];
});
```

Basically, I want to check a value from the headers before I send the data.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this from the [manual](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)

```
httpBackend.whenPOST('/movies',data, function(headers){
  return headers['Authorization'] == 'xxx';
})
.respond(function(method, url, data) {
```